# Display Data in Group and Horizontal

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a WPF application and I want to design a window that appears like below:

[image: Categories stacked vertically, containing tiles with name and image for products stacked horizontally.]

Basically, I want the products to be grouped by category and the products in that category are displayed horizontally first and then vertically.

Which control or way is most efficient to do this?

Comment: You could have a listbox for categories.

Comment: Nest a listbox for products in that per item

Comment: Please provide code or details on what you have tried beforehand, then it is easier and often faster to provide a good answer or any answer at all.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that you have created data structures for your catgories and products like this:

```
public class Category
{
   public Category(string name)
   {
      Name = name;
      Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
   }

   public string Name { get; }

   public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; }
}
```

```
public class Product
{
   public Product(string name, ImageSource image)
   {
      Name = name;
      Image = image;
   }

   public string Name { get; }

   public ImageSource Image { get; }
}
```

Each `Category` has a name and a collection of `Product`s. The collection is an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-6.0) so you can add, insert or remove products at runtime and the user interface is automatically notified of the changes and adopts them accordingly. If you want the names or the collection itself to be interchangable, you have to [implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). If your collections never change, a [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0) or a similar type is sufficient. Each `Product` has a name and an [`ImageSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imagesource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) that points to the image to be displayed.

The categories are exposed as a property of[`ObservableCollection<Category>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-6.0) in your view model.

```
public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; }
```

Fill the `Categories` and `Products` collections with your data, e.g.:

```
Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>
{
   new Category("First"),
   new Category("Second"),
   new Category("Third"),
   new Category("Fourth"),
   // ...other categories.
};

Categories[0].Products.Add(new Product("Product 1.1", new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Your/Resources/YourImage.png"))));
// ...other products in various categories.
```

The XAML markup to display the categories and products looks like this:

```
<Grid Background="Gray">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                  Margin="0, 20">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="local:Category">
                <Border BorderThickness="0, 1, 0, 0"
                        BorderBrush="Black">
                    <StackPanel Margin="10, 0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Margin="0, 10"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="NoProductTextBlock"
                                   Text="No product"
                                   Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <ListBox x:Name="ProductsListBox"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
                                 BorderThickness="0"
                                 Background="Transparent"
                                 Margin="0, 0, 0, 10"
                                 Visibility="Visible">
                            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="local:Product">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                   Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Products.Count}" Value="0">
                        <Setter TargetName="NoProductTextBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ProductsListBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

What does the markup do to create the user interface you want to achieve?

- There is an outer `Grid` that is only there for showing the background for demo purposes.

  - An [`ItemsControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is the base type for controls showing multiple items of a collection. It does not have any style for states like *Mouse Over* or *Selected*, it just displays items. Bind the `Categories` property to it, so it displays each `Category` object.

    - A [`DataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) is created to tell the `ItemsControl` *how to display* a `Category`.

      - A `Border` creates the top horizontal line of each category.
      - The `StackPanel` contains the elements for the category and the establishes the margin.

        - A `TextBlock` displays the name of the category by binding `Name`.
        - A `TextBlock` displays the placeholder text if there are no products.
        - A [`ListBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) displays all of the `Product`s of a `Category`. It is bound to the `Products` property inside `Category`. In contrast to an `ItemsControl`, a `ListBox` has states for *MouseOver*, *Focused* and *Selected* which is what you want to interact with products.

          - As items panel, a [`WrapPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.wrappanel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is used.

            > Positions child elements in sequential position from left to right, breaking content to the next line at the edge of the containing box. Subsequent ordering happens sequentially from top to bottom or from right to left, depending on the value of the `Orientation` property.
          - Another `DataTemplate` is used to tell the `ListBox` *how to display* a `Product`. This is simply an `Image` and a `TextBlock` stacked vertically.
    - A [`DataTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is used to observe the [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.count?view=net-6.0) property of the `Products` collection. If there are no products - `Count` is zero - we collapse the `ListBox` and show the placeholder `TextBlock` instead.

This is what the result looks like with some dummy data:

[image: Categories arranged vertically containing horizontally arranged products with name and image as tile.]